# Rails wrong model namespace lookup in scoped controllers if same name exists in global namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Question-model declared like this:

```
Question < ActiveRecord::Base
```

*app/models/question.rb*

and a Quiz::Question-model declared like this:

```
Quiz::Question < ActiveRecord::Base
```

*app/models/quiz/question.rb*

In addition, I have a quiz-model in app/models/quiz.rb.

Now the problem is  if I call `::Quiz::Question.inspect` (OR .table_name OR .name OR everything else) from a view in some scoped controllers, it returns me information about my question-model in the global namespace, not of the question-model in the quiz-namespace. This means ruby still points to my Question-class in the global namespace instead of using the one I specified with the Quiz::-namespace.

How can I call my Quiz::Question-class without renaming my global namespaced question-model?

**Experiment for clearification**

If I add thes methods to both classes:

```
class Question
  def self.test
    'Hello from global Question'
  end
end

class Quiz::Question
  def self.test
    'Hello form namespace Quiz'
  end
end
```

and then just call `::Quiz::Question.test` (or `Quiz::Question.test`) it shows up "Hello from global Question" in some scoped controllers and views (route with `scope :module => "..."`). If I call ::Quiz::Question from a view or controller acting in my global namespace (like application.html.erb), it shows the expected result (-> question model in quiz-namespace).

Comment: Maybe you have to restart your rails server?

Comment: Can you paste your `$:` variable value as well?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I already tried this many times :/

Comment: How does your `Quiz` module look like?

Comment: Just updated my question, it has anything to do with controller scopes.. I do not have an explicit quiz-module-definition. Since I also have a quiz-model (global namespace), I can't define a quiz-module. So "Quiz" is a model, too, not a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know exactly what the problem was (maybe it has something to do with rails autoloading), but I solved it by adding a "require" statement in my quiz-model:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'quiz/question'
end
```

in *app/models/quiz.rb*

Comment: this worked for me as well. namespaced models w/o a module.  issues in a (unrelated) controller namespace. would love to know why this occurs. did you ever figure out what's going on under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

For those coming here looking for an answer related to classes, not tables, it seems that ruby does not distinguish between two classes of the same name in different namespaces, so you should always name the class itself differently.

Here's an explanation:
https://makandracards.com/makandra/20633-ruby-constant-lookup-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly

Comment: That sucks.  I was getting this problem using `Role.all` when I ran `Admin::Role.all`.  I don't get the point of namespacing then...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table name explicitly in the model, but shouldn't you be calling `Quiz::Question.table_name` not `::Quiz::Question.table_name`? or is that a typo?

```
class Quiz::Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'quiz_questions'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem isn't the wrong table name, the problem is that ruby used the wrong model (the question-model instead of the Quiz::Question-model). Guess I get the "root" path by adding "::" to the front of the call, but it doesn't make a difference - the problem still remains, if I call "Quiz::Question" instad of "::Quiz::Question".

Answer (score 0):

It is accessing the constant you want to access, just the `table_name` returns some value for both classes. Also the `inspect` method for ActiveRecord::Base is defined to display the content of the database table, and since both classes points to the same table, the result is identitcal for both clasees. You can check that it is calling the right class with:

```
::Quiz::Question.name
```

### Experiment

Try define method test on both classes:

```
class Question
  def self.test
    'Hello from global Question'
  end
end

class Quiz::Question
  def self.test
    'Hello form namespace Quiz'
  end
end
```

Then do:

```
::Quiz::Question.test
```

And see what result you'll get

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is not the table_name. If I use "name" or "inspect", it will show me the name or information about the global Question-model. The problem is ::Quiz::Question always points to the question-model in my global namespace, not to the Question-model in the Quiz-namespace.

Comment: @Experience - It does not, at least it shouldn't. How are you checking for this?

Comment: ::Quiz::Question.inspect returns me information about my question-model in the global namespace, not in my quiz namespace.

Comment: @Experience - Could you edit your question to show its result and what would you expect. It is natural that inspect will return the same for both classes as they point to the same database table.

Comment: Just added my question with the results of your experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `table_name_prefix` in your `Quiz` module:

```
# app/models/quiz.rb
module Quiz
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'quiz_'
  end
end

# app/models/quiz/question.rb
class Quiz::Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Afterwards:

```
Question.table_name
#=> "questions"

Quiz::Question.table_name
#=> "quiz_questions"
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have already set the table_name_prefix in that module. Just edited my question for clearification. The problem is not the table_name, the general problem is ruby always points to the question-model in the global namespace instead of that one in the quiz-namespace.

Comment: Are you sure?  Are you checking with things other than just the table name?

Comment: @Experience works for me `::Quiz::Question == Quiz::Question #=> true`

Comment: Weird - if I call ::Quiz::Question.inspect in rails console, it shows up my question-model in my quiz-namespace. But if I make the same call in my controller or in my view, it shows up the question-model of the global namespace..

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for your both Quiz::Question & Question models, even if your Models are different, Rails will think that they have the same table name, unless you specify it :

```
class Quiz::Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.table_name_prefix
  'quiz_'
  end

  [...]

end
```